# Faster typeahead search for table rows

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to implement typeahead search/filtering on a large table (1000+ rows 100+ columns).

Codepen link -> https://codepen.io/davidatthepark/pen/KmYPEv?editors=1010 (could only fit 600 rows and 60 columns).

I'm noticing some lag when I type numbers and remove them quickly. Is there a more efficient way to do this? A coworker suggested mocking the dom with an array or object, manipulating it and then rendering the dom with that new state (sounds similar to react).

JavaScript code:

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', search);

function search() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var searchString = this.value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i< rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].textContent.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
      rows[i].classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      rows[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: don't run it on each key up, run it with an idle timer set to 150ms or so

Comment: Your coworker is 100% correct. Although, if your regexp matches all of them (say one character, the letter "a") then re-rendering that takes a lot of effort. You should consider paginating your table as well, which will be a cinch when it's backed by an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a regular expression and string operation on every row for every key stroke. Just cache the data first and then search the cache:

[Updated fiddle](https://codepen.io/macrotower/pen/wdZBzE)

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', search);

var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
// build up cache
var rowCache = new Array(rows.length)
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rowCache[i] = rows[i].textContent.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
}

function search() {
  var start = Date.now();
  var searchString = this.value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i< rows.length; i++) {
    if (rowCache[i].indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
      rows[i].classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      rows[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('speed').value = Date.now() - start;
}
```

This was considerably faster for me.